# How efficient is to use AWS AutoScaling for scheduling start and stop an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to achieve scheduling start and stop AWS EC2 instance without using other AWS Services(CloudWatch, Lambda)

I'm planning to use AutoScaling for scheduling purpose. But looks like it will terminate and launch EC2 instance from custom AMI not actual start/stop existing EC2 instance.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: _WHY_ do you not wish to use other services? Do you have any Amazon EC2 instances on which you can run some code (eg a `cron` job), or a computer elsewhere that can run the schedule?

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. I'm planning to perform EC2 instance activities (including scheduling) with using EC2 API.

Comment: _WHY_ do you not wish to use other services? If you don't use another AWS service, you will need a computer (either EC2 or your own computer) to start/stop instances on a schedule.

Comment: My goal is not to use other AWS services except AWS EC2 for scheduling task. I don't like to use computer or another EC2 instance to take care of cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaling permits you to place instances into standby in order to temporarily remove them from an autoscaling group.

You could conceivably do this to add / remove capacity from your ASGs as necessary, but the manner in which ASGs usually work is to create and terminate EC2 instances in response to demand.

I cannot offhand think of an AWS-based-way to schedule starting / stopping of an EC2 without using Cloudwatch.  You could have an EC2 control server that used the AWS sdk to start / stop a pool of instances in response to cron jobs, but this is a great way to build an unmaintainable infrastructure.